# Bot cannot connect voice channel

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

Bot won't connect to channel and play music because it gives the error.:
`AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'is_voice_connected'`
I checked out some discord.py tutorials and wrote this code:

```
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
songs = asyncio.Queue()
play_next_song = asyncio.Event()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready')
async def audio_player_task():
    while True:
        play_next_song.clear()
        current = await songs.get()
        current.start()
        await play_next_song.wait()
def toggle_next():
    client.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(play_next_song.set)
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not client.is_voice_connected(ctx.message.server):
        voice = await client.join_voice_channel(ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
    else:
        voice = client.voice_client_in(ctx.message.server)
    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(url, after=toggle_next)
    await songs.put(player)
client.loop.create_task(audio_player_task())
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using the discord.py rewrite or any previous version, but the only way I can see this not working is that you are using the wrong version of discord.py. [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) is where you can find the correct documentation for your code.

Also, the issue with the error about checking if your bot is connected, client doesn't find your voice connection in the rewrite of discord.py. All you need there is

```
from discord.utils import get

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    voice_client = get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice_client.is_connected():
        #Do this
    else:
        #Do that
```

If you need anything else worked out, most of the changes from the original discord.py to the rewrite is in the documentation I provided in this answer.